# I am trying to capture packets from a raspberry pi for just a second to get the packets per second ratio

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, wireshark, tshark, pyshark

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface = 'wlan0')

capture.sniff(timeout=1)

print(capture)
```

I get this as result: "LiveCapture (0 packets)"

But how is possible to get 0 packets all the time?

Comment: Do you still get this issue if you capture for a longer time? It started working for me with a timeout>=3.

Comment: With timeout>=3 i get a good number of packages. But my problem is that I need packages per second every second in Real-Time so that can't solve my problem.

Comment: When you say "packages", do you mean apt packages or the like?

Comment: I mean packets, sorry for that.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the interface's statistics?

Comment: There are not statistics in pyshark.

Comment: I meant the statistics of your network interface. I'm guessing you're running Linux. Can't you retrieve the statistics from `/proc/net/dev`, or `ifconfig`, or `ip -s link`?

Comment: I want to receive the packets per second in real time. Why should I use the statistics?

Comment: My bad, I though you wanted to measure the "packets per second ratio". What you want is to receive packets with a <=1s delay, right?

Comment: No I want to measure "packets per second ratio" every second as you said but getting it through the python code. i.e 20 packets/second, 200 packets/second and so.....

Comment: Well, the Linux statistics give you the number of packets at all time from which you can compute the packet per second speed. I don't get why you can't use the statistics.

Comment: Because I want that in real-time.